# Rails 4 - coding through models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **user** model, with a separate **profile** model. Each user has a profile. I then have 8 models for things within a profile (for example, each profile has a dashboard, feedback and publications). The **profile belongs_to user and the dashboard etc belongs_to profile**.

I am creating a profile view and would like to know how I write the line of code that will collate relevant information from the other models to display in the profile.

For example,the profile will be displayed with the name of its owner (which is stored in the user model). It will also have feedback stored in the feedback model. Is there a way to write that the profile view should display the **user.first_name user.last_name**, and **`user.feedback`**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain calls through Profile, like so:

```
@profile.user.first_name
```

But this violates a principle known as the “Law of Demeter”. There's a complex definition, but suffice to say that when you are accessing one object (`User`) through another (`Profile`), you begin to violate this law. It's not a huge deal when you're accessing user properties through the profile, necessarily, but things get messy quickly:

```
@dashboard.profile.feedback.order(:rating).where(user: @dashboard.profile.user)
```

Gross. And brittle, too. When you need to compose multiple models into a single view, there's a better pattern known as a Decorator. The job of a decorator is to give you a single object that appropriately collects data from the models for presentation, without tying your view code directly to your models. For example:

```
class DashboardDecorator
  def initialize(dashboard, profile, user)
    @dashboard = dashboard
    @profile = profile
    @user = user
  end

  def full_name
    "#{@user.first_name} #{@user.last_name}"
  end

  def feedback_count
    @profile.feedback.count
  end

  def days_since_last_post
    Date.today - @dashboard.last_login
  end
end

# /app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb
def show
  # ...
  @dashboard = DashboardDecorator.new(dashboard, profile, current_user)
end
```

Then your view can access the data through the decorator:

```
<%= @dashboard.full_name %>
```

While you can write your own decorators like above, things get pretty tedious pretty quick. If you like to automate some of these parts, you should check out [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper), a handy gem that makes creating decorators a little easier, especially when your decorator methods map 1:1 with model methods.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. Does this mean that you can have several different decorators using the same underlying models?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I recommend you spend an hour reading up on the myriad opinions (and definitions) of Decorators, Presenters, Exhibitors, View Objects, View Models, etc in Ruby. There's a lot of good stuff out there, and none of it is really ubiquitous yet.

Comment: This is a good place to start — it talks about a lot more than just decorators and views, though. http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Thanks very much Corey. I'll check it out.